# Overlapped first and second page when using e.HasMorePages

Tags: c#

I want to print a receipt from the form containing checklist with 2 bills in a "A4" paper.when 2 bills are printed in one sheet and if the checklist has greater than 2 item checked then the new must be added . I am trying it from several hrs and tried to use e.HasMorePages to print multiple pages. Still Now when I click print, the second page overlaps to the first page. I searched example for 3 hours ago but unfortunately it does not work

Please help.

```
 private void print(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ChkListConnectedTap.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {

                flagFor = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < ChkListConnectedTap.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                {

                    customerNumSelected = global.ObjDboperation.InEnglish(ChkListConnectedTap.Items[i].ToString());
                    loadYearmonths1(customerNumSelected);
                    Initialize(customerNumSelected);

                    //plotting coordinates
                    yPos = 5 + count * 540;
                    InitPt = new Point(50, Convert.ToInt32(yPos));
                    LeftSideMeterReader(e);
                    RightSideMeterReader(e);

                    //check wheter the plotted coodinated greater than maximum height of page.
                    if (AddMorePages(e, yPos, count) && pages <= (Convert.ToInt32(ChkListConnectedTap.CheckedItems.Count / 2) + 1))
                        {
                            e.HasMorePages = true;
                            count = 0;
                            pages++;
                            continue;

                        }

                      else
                    {
                        e.HasMorePages = false;
                    }

                    count++;
                }

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("सुरुमा ग्राहक संख्या छान्नुहोस् !", global.msgCaptionHead, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }

    }

    private bool AddMorePages(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e,float PosY,int cnt) {
        if (PosY + 560 >= 1100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The `continue` must be `return`.  The `i` variable must be a field of the outer class, initialize it to 0 with a BeginPrint event handler.

Comment: thanks Hans. I have solved it using break instead of continue and put a static variable on i and initialized pages and count in BeingPrint event handler. Its Working now.